# dismiss any facebook dialog before orientation change

Tags: android, facebook, orientation-changes

I'm using Facebook Android SDK in my app. The authorize method cause to run FbDialog which shows spinner while authorization page loading. If orientation change occurs during this dialog running the application crashes with "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager" How to avoid crushing and continue loading authorization page or at least restart it without setting activity to support one of landscape/portrait orientation?

Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pur this in manifest

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
```

this wont restart your activity on orientation change..